# MediaPlayer error 100 & 38 while using two MediaPlayer objects

Tags: android, media-player

I'm trying to build a game which plays some sounds **effects on click & at the same time music in the background**.

I tried implementing this with **two MediaPlayer objects**.
The first one, which served for the effects on click works great.

The second one however sometimes logs **error 100, sometimes error 38**. No sound at all.

Variables

```
private MediaPlayer mEffects;
private MediaPlayer mpSoundBackground;
```

Implementation of the sound media player:

```
mpSoundBackground = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.soundbackground1small);
        mpSoundBackground.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Logger.d("prepared");
                musicPrepared = true;
            }
        });
        mpSoundBackground.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                Logger.d("error "+what);
                return false;
            }
        });

 if (musicPrepared) {
            mpSoundBackground.start();
            Logger.d("music is prepared");
        } else {
            Logger.d("music is not prepared");
        }
```

Implementation of the effects Media Player:

```
   stopPlaying();
   mEffects= MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.soundhit);
   mEffects.start();


private void stopPlaying() {
    if (mEffects!= null) {
        mEffects.stop();
        mEffects.release();
        mEffects= null;
    }
}
```

*Update*

> To add to the confusion: It does seem to work in emulator
>   (Genymotion), but does not work on my OnePlus One, running Lollipop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't make the errors go away, until I reconverted my soundfile to MP3.
Now it plays both on device & simulator without any problems.

Moral of this story: if you are running into errors, try a few encodings of the same file (possibly a few file sizes too!), it might be the solution.

Comment: MediaPlayer support some formats, http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core, check this link to know it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `setOnPreparedListener` method for both players. also if you want to play a sound on clicks consider using [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html).

Also in the `public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)` method, you can use `mp.start` there is no need for that flag, since you can not know for sure that it is prepared once you reach that prepared flag